# How can I tell which other projects in my enterprise use my shared workflow?

Tags: github-actions

I'm maintaining a shared workflow in GitHub Actions within our enterprise account.

Is there a way for me to tell which projects within the enterprise use my workflow other than doing a code search for the URL?

Comment: No as far as I'm aware; you could include something that "phones home" when it's used but others might consider that invasive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to Insights > Dependency graph > Dependents (URL `https://github.com/ORG/REPO/network/dependents`), you'll see all repositories that use a specific reusable workflow; you can pick the workflow for which you want to see dependents in the top right "Package" selector:

[image: Package selector]

The whole page might look like this (for [my repo](https://github.com/bewuethr/workflows)):

[image: List of dependent repos]

And to filter that list to your enterprise, you can select an owner at the top of that list.

Notice that this works only for public repositories!

Comment: Thanks, this looked promising - except the page tells me:

**GitHub does not currently determine the dependents of private repositories**

What am I missing here?

Comment: @semmelbroesel The repo I show is public, so you're likely not missing anything, and it's only supported for public repoistories.

Comment: Bummer, but good to know, and thanks for your reply!